# How to stub property on factory object in RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

How do I stub this property?

user.rb

```
def my_method
  scheduling_frequency_minutes = self.business.settings_group.scheduling_frequency.minutes
  # where scheduling_frequency is an integer field in the settings_group model
  # but this is still set to the default (60), not 30
end
```

user_spec.rb

```
it "get available time slots (on the half hour)" do

  # 1st attempt:
  @business.settings_group.scheduling_frequency = 30
  # where @business is the same Business pointed to by 'self.business' in the user.rb model

  # 2nd attempt:
  #Business.stub_chain(:settings_group, :scheduling_frequency).and_return(30)

  #3rd attempt:

  settings_group = mock("settings_group")
  settings_group.stub(:scheduling_frequency).and_return(30)
  @business.should_receive(:settings_group).and_return(settings_group)

  @business.users.all.first.my_method
end
```

**UPDATE:**

Here's my latest attempt and it STILL doesn't work. What's going on??

```
user = @business.users.all.first
user.stub_chain(:business, :settings_group, :scheduling_frequency).and_return(30)
user.my_method()
```

-

```
  def my_method
    debugger
    # p self.business.settings_group.scheduling_frequency -> 60
  end
```

Comment: stub_chain is my preference in this situation.

Comment: I tried it, as in the code above, but it didn't work.

Comment: Did you tried to stub also `self` call? I.e. `user.stub_chain('self.business.setting_group.scheduling_frequency').and_return 30`?

Answer (score 2):

You need to stub chain the whole way and in the correct context (in this case, user)

```
user = User.new
user.stub_chain(:business, :settings_group, :scheduling_frequency).and_return(30)
user.my_method
```

I tried the following standalone and it worked.  (I did this outside of rails so the minutes method was not available.)

```
require 'rspec'

class User
  def my_method
    scheduling_frequency_minutes = self.business.settings_group.scheduling_frequency
  end
end

describe User do
  it "get available time slots (on the half hour)" do
    user = User.new
    user.stub_chain(:business, :settings_group, :scheduling_frequency).and_return(30)
    user.my_method.should eql(30)
  end

end
```

Comment: Ack, it's still not working. see my "UPDATE" in the original post. Thanks.

Comment: See my edits.  The stub_chain works fine.  What error are you getting?